# Send all files in folder as separate attachments

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to attach all files in a folder in separate emails using a modified version of this code from https://www.slipstick.com/developer/macro-send-files-email/.

```
Dim fldName As String

Sub SendFilesbyEmail()
' From http://slipstick.me/njpnx
Dim sFName As String

i = 0
fldName = "C:\Users\Test"
sFName = Dir(fldName)
Do While Len(sFName) > 0
'filter for only *.txt
  If Right(sFName, 4) = ".txt" Then
      Call SendasAttachment(sFName)
      i = i + 1
  End If
  sFName = Dir
Loop
MsgBox i & " files were sent"
End Sub

Function SendasAttachment(fName As String)

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olMsg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim olAtt As Outlook.Attachments

Dim localfName As String
Dim localfldName As String

Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set olMsg = olApp.CreateItem(0) ' email
Set olAtt = olMsg.Attachments

' attach file
olAtt.Add (fldName & fName)
localfName = fName

   ' send message
With olMsg
  .Subject = "PDF Import: " & Left(localfName, Len(localfName) - 4)
  .To = "test@test.com"
  .HTMLBody = "Test"
  .Send
End With
End Function
```

The issue comes with trying to put the file name into the email subject.

```
.Subject = "PDF Import: " & Left(localfName, Len(localfName) - 4)
```

If I remove localfName from the subject, to send a generic subject for all emails, the code works fine.

When I put either fName or localfName (my attempt to debug the issue), the first email sends, but on the second iteration, the DIR function returns a file name from a different folder, and the code breaks because the file it's trying to attach can't be found.

Comment: Consider using a `Scripting.FileSystemObject` for a more robust solution. Also `fName` should probably be passed `ByVal`.

Comment: Try `sFName = Dir(fldName & "\*.txt")` instead of `sFName = Dir(fldName)` - that'll eliminate the need to verify the extension, ...and could very well just fix it.

Comment: Do you have any other VBA code running as event handlers that would be firing in response to your `SendasAttachment` function?  The state of `Dir` is application global, so if you're invoking it anywhere else that would cause this behavior.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thanks for the suggestion, I did try that at first and had the same issue too.

Comment: @Comintern I think that's the problem! I didn't realize that until you suggested it, but there is indeed another module running in my Outlook (didn't think about it because I wasn't the one who set that up) and sure enough, it includes the Dir function. But then I wonder why the code works fine when I don't insert the string returned by the Dir function into the email subject...

Comment: Pretty sure the subject thing is a red herring: your princess is in another castle -- `Dir` working off whatever the current value of `CurDir` is, is a much more likely cause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a FileSystem object and then loop through all files in the directory like the following:

```
Sub SendFilesbyEmail()
    Dim objFSO as object
    Dim objFldr as Object
    Dim objFile  as Object

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFldr = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\Test")

    For Each objFile In objFldr.Files 
        strFullPath = objFldr.Path  & "\" & objFile.Name

        If LCase(Trim(objFSO.GetExtensionName(strFullPath))) = "txt" Then
            SendasAttachment(strFullPath)
        End If
    Next


    set objFldr = nothing
    set objFSO = nothing
End Sub


Function SendasAttachment(fullPath As String)

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olMsg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim olAtt As Outlook.Attachments

    Dim localfName As String
    Dim localfldName As String

    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set olMsg = olApp.CreateItem(0) ' email
    Set olAtt = olMsg.Attachments

    ' attach file
    olAtt.Add (fullPath)
    localfName = fName

      '  send message
    With olMsg
      .Subject = "PDF Import: " & Left(fullPath, Len(fullPath) - 4)
      .To = "test@test.com"
      .HTMLBody = "Test"
      .Send
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for the post! I did find a website showing the FileSystem Object method but couldn't get it to work, but your code works great. One basic question: if I wanted to pass another String object into the function, what's the right syntax for that? SendasAttachment(strfullPath, secondStr) gives compiler error, and Call SendasAttachment(...,...) gives a runtime error... (this is after I have correctly declared two String objects in Function SendasAttachment(fullPath As String, secondString As String).